# textfield in closure swift

Tags: swift, firebase, uitextfield, closures

```
    let creatorDB = Database.database().reference().child("A")
    creatorDB.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let B = snapshot.value as! String
        print(B)

        let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("\(B))/Messages/")


        let messageDictionary = ["Sender": Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid , "MessageBody": TextField.text!]

            messageDB.childByAutoId().setValue(messageDictionary) {

                (error, reference) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                } else {
                    print("message saved succesfully")

                    self.chatTextField.isEnabled = true
                    self.sendButton.isEnabled = true
                    self.TextField.text = ""
                }

        }

    }
```

when I use this code, I can't retrieve the Messagebody,
I guess self.textfield.text doesn't work,
how can I fix for the self.textfield.text in closure

Comment: Change `TextField` name to something else and remove old outlet from storyboard and reconnect it again and try.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni it is not for rename, it is from UITextField

Comment: Show more code to understand the issue.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni the problem is - that textfield.text without closure works for savaing messagebody, but with in that closure Xcode say I have to write "self." in front of textfield, so after I put it, messagebody doesn't conatain value from " self.textfield.text "

Comment: @DharmeshKheni this is work

messageDictionary = ["Sender": Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid , "MessageBody": TextField.text!]

this is doesn't work

{ (snapshot) in 
 let messageDictionary = ["Sender": Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid , "MessageBody": self.TextField.text!] }

Comment: Please update you question with what works and what is not working. And what error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try saving textfield text in some variable and try. I am writing answer since i am not able to comment on your post. And if any further help needed, Please be sure what you want exactly.. Here to help.

Comment: Will you please elaborate your problem. What exactly you want to do.

Comment: First please remove textField outlet and rename it with tfDoe and reconnect the outlet and then try to use your tfDoe.

Comment: And i recommend you to save textField.text in some another variable and use that variable.